# How to add nodes at specified positions in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to add nodes at specified positions. I started off by trying to add two nodes at the same position (x=0, y=0) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
});

cy.add([
  { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n0" }, position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
  { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n1" }, position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
]);

});
```

And I expected it to show me two nodes at the same position, one over the other. But the result was quite unexpected. Here is what I got:

[image]

In fact, the position of the nodes remains the same no matter what values of x and y I specify. I also tried `renderedPosition` instead of `position` but to no avail.

I am searching the Cytoscape documentation for how to achieve what I want but I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. I was forgetting to specify that the preset layout must be used. Added the following:

```
layout: {
  name: 'preset'
},
```

to the cy object and it works.

Comment: var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    ready: function(){console.log('ready');},
    layout: {
     name: 'preset'
    }
   });

Comment: @AkshayDamle : +1 for figuring out the answer yourself before anyone else could. :)